# \limits and \biggl\lparen

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

When I type `\biggl\lparen` before `\int\limits`, where `\limits` puts the domain over which I'm integrating under the integral sign, the bottom end of the left parenthesis touch — or is too close to — the domain symbol ; and it causes poor readability.

Here is an example :

```
\biggl\lparen \int\limits_{\{\lvert x \rvert > R \}} u(x) dx \biggr\rparen
```

I have overcome this difficulty by adding a space after the left parenthesis with `\>`. More precisely, I defined the following PairedDelimiter :

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\parens}[1]{\lparen}{\rparen}{\> #1}
```

However, I am not satisfied by this « solution » because I do not need the extra spacing all the time, and that makes `\parens` not flexible at all.

I don't want to use `\left` and `\right`, since they make the parentheses too big ; nor `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` which make the parentheses too small.

I'm open to any suggestion.

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Maybe you would be happier with `\[\biggl(\int\limits_{\mathrlap{\{|x|>R\}}} u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\biggr)\]`? This requires the package `mathtools` instead of `amsmath`. We do not know, what you use, due to the missing MWE.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi `\lparen` and `\rparen` are defined by `mathtools`

Comment: @karlkoeller thanks. Never seen them. I will have to read about those. Can't see their advantage in the OP.

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks. I should have done that before posting. My apologies!

Comment: @LaRiFari Unfortunately, I want the integration domain to be centered under the integral sign. But thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it looks like you're using the `mathtools` package (good move!), I suggest you do the following:

- use the `\smashoperator[r]{...}` directive (provided by the `mathtools` package) to eliminate the whitespace between the integral symbol and the integrand;
- define a new macro called `\abs` using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`;
- define the macro `\parens` using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` as well, and use `\parens[\bigg]{...}` to generate the bigg-sized parentheses;
- insert a thinspace between the integrand and `dx`; optional: write `\mathrm{d}x` if you want the "differential operator" set in upright rather than in italic mode;
- add a bit of whitespace after `\biggl\lparen` to separate visually the large opening parenthesis from the domain of integration (`\,\,` seems about right to me, but your preferences may differ); and
- omit the curly braces around the expression for the domain of integration.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{\lparen}{\rparen}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\texttt{before:}&\quad
\biggl\lparen \int\limits_{\{\lvert x \rvert > R \}} u(x) dx \biggr\rparen\\[2ex]
\texttt{after:}&\quad
\parens[\bigg]{\,\, \smashoperator[r]{\int\limits_{\abs{x}> R }} u(x) \, dx }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In a follow-up comment, the OP mentioned that he/she uses the `mathptmx` package, and that `\bigg`-sized parentheses turn out to be too big and that `\Big`-sized parentheses are not big enough. I suggest looking into using the [MathTime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font package, which provides high-quality math fonts based on Times Roman. (The complete `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge. However, its "lite" subset, which is all that's needed for the present example, *is* free of charge.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}    % Times Roman text font
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} % Times Roman math font
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{\lparen}{\rparen}
\begin{document}
\[
\parens[\bigg]{\mkern6mu \smashoperator[r]{\int\limits_{\abs{x}> R }} \! u(x) \, dx }
\]
\end{document}
```

One may also give the `newtxmath` package (load it with the option `cmintegrals`) a try. In my opinion, though, the large parentheses produced by `newtxmath` look rather anemic; they're certainly not as handsome as those that are produced by the `mtpro2` package. Moreover, it's necessary to use `\Bigg` as the sizing directive the parentheses.

[image]

(Same code as in the preceding MWE, with `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}` replaced with `\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxmath}`, and with `\Bigg` instead of `\bigg` as the sizing instruction.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm using the package `mathptmx` (Times New Roman) and I just found out that the parentheses are a bit longer than in `Computer Modern` ; this is why they overlap the integration domain when there are no extra spaces. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Gatz - With `mathptmx` loaded, I think it would be perfectly OK to use `\Big` as the sizing instruction, i.e., to write `\parens[\Big]{\,\, ...}`. `\bigg` definitely generates parentheses that are overly tall. Note that I'd still use `\,\,` -- or, equivalently, `\mkern6mu` -- to insert some added whitespace following the opening left parenthesis.

Comment: Unfortunately, `\Big` is a bit too short: the bottom end of the left parenthesis doesn't go between the bottom end of the integral sign and the integration domain. I don't know if my explanations are clear... However, is it possible to use the Times font for the text and the Computer Modern font for the math mode? Thanks!

Comment: @Gatz - I would *not* try to mix-and-match Times Roman and Computer Modern; they are just too different along various dimensions. By the way, it is not absolutely necessary (typographically speaking) for the parentheses to be at least as tall as the integral symbol that they enclose. It's purely a matter of taste.

Comment: Ok. However, I'll give `newtxtext` a try. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Gatz - I've posted an addendum to show the output produced by using the `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` math font packages. Personally, I prefer the output produced by `mtpro2`...

Comment: Working with MathTime Professional II (Lite) seems rather restrictive. In addition, the text font is not — in my opinion and that's a matter of taste — better looking than the one of `mathptmx`. However, I must admit that the parentheses are nice — yet they also require extra spacing `\,\,`. Anyway, I think extra spacing will always be needed — and that was the main issue. I'll probably go with `mathptmx`, which I like ; or with `newtxtext` and keep Computer Modern as font in math mode. I remain open to any further suggestion. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Mico has already given some nice ideas which provide a beautiful result. However, I am posting my idea from comment as well, as it is quite short and might serve you here:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document} 
    \[\biggl(\int\limits_{\mathrlap{\abs{x}>R}} u(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\biggr)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but remove the braces...

Comment: @karlkoeller done. But I think they were wanted by the OP. Well, no problem to add them again...